# Are rogue intents possible or is something else happening?

Tags: android, android-intent

### Background

We have a legacy Android app which has recently developed a wild bug. It's not affecting many users but it breaks all functionality requiring admin and support to be involved. It is bad enough that it has to be fixed. We have not been able to reproduce the bug and there is no logging.

The current team does not have much or any Android experience and aren't familiar with the code base.

### Error Description

The app has three states:

1. Activated, tokens
2. Activated, no tokens
3. Not-activated, no tokens

Something is causing the app to go from state (1) to state (2), i.e. tokens are being lost or deleted. After this the app remains in state (2).

- API 7
- Occurs on Android 4.1 +
- Re-occurs for some users
- Tokens are retrieved from a server & stored on device.

### Theory

The app can be launched via a browsable intent which will delete all tokens and "re-activate" it. This will send it from state (1) to state (2).

### Code Description

Intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
  <data android:scheme="myscheme" />

  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

Start code:

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Uri activationUrl = getIntent().getData();
    boolean busyActivating = (activationUrl != null);

    if (busyActivating) {
        // delete tokens
        // save activation url
        // state - activated no tokens
    } else if (isActivated()) {
        startNormally();
    } else {
        askToActivate();
    }
}
```

### Conclusion

To me it *looks* like there is some type of rogue intent causing and activated app to enter the *busyActivating* flow.

I was able to replicate this by forcing the intent twice but it has been confirmed that users aren't doing this.

Is this at all possible? Is something else going on here?

---

EDIT: We couldn't figure out why this was happening and in the end I just changed the code to be a bit more robust and hoped for the best. 
Even though this question will get old and die, if you do come across it in the future please respond if you experienced something similar!

Comment: Where do you get the tokens? Where do you store them?

Comment: They are retrieved from a server and stored on the phone. They can only be retrieved once.

Comment: Are you sure the intent is from `BROWSABLE`? If the user sends the application to background and then returns to it using its launcher icon, it would send an intent without any data.

Comment: In this case though wouldn't the `getIntent().getData()` return null? If so `busyActivating` would be false and it won't cause the error. I wasn't able to reproduce it on the test phones by doing the above so I don't think so.

Comment: Oh, it checks for not null. In that case just switching to the browser and clicking on the link that lauches your application again will send another intent with data and reset activation of your application.

Comment: Yes! Exactly! But we know that users aren't doing that. (We are going to update the code to avoid this in future)

Comment: I think it may be possible if the user opens another application on top of yours (eg. starting settings from the status bar) and then presses back to return to your application. It would run `onStart` but there should be no new intent so the one you had already used would be returned by `getIntent`.

Comment: Good idea but it doesn't reproduce the error. :( We've decided to make a "logging" build for users experiencing the issue to use. Hopefully it will yield more info.